# htacces opencart redirect https not work corectly

Tags: ssl, mod-rewrite, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

After I redirected to https some of the links no longer work:

ex:
domain/category - it's ok
domain/product - it's ok
domain/category/product - not work
domain/category/category/product - not work

It looks like the page doesn't load CSS, just links.

Can anyone help me with an advice, code, example to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

 ### Ptr SSL
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
 #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 #RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on   
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 #end SSL

 RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
 RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
 RewriteRule ^system/download/(.*) index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)

 RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have one of my sites:

```
RewriteBase /

# SSL & www
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
# end SSL & www

RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I also have "SSL" set to "Yes" in the Settings as well as SEO URLs enabled. I know the two Rewrite Conditions could be condensed but my site breaks when I do that so I'm happy to leave them as is

**Edit** Having seen your comment with the site URL, the issue doesn't appear to be the .htaccess but instead the page's `<base>` element's src value is `"(unknown)"` this is the element that contains the base URL of the site for all relative links.

So the 404 errors were indicating that the browser is assuming the "SEO-friendly" category name is a real subfolder and that the css files are stored there. In other words it thinks that there is a folder called "public_html/Accesorii" and the css files are there.

What you need to do is look in the theme settings or manually edit the head.php file, it should be somewhere in `/catalog/view/theme/fastor/common/` folder.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for the reply.
I tested your code, but I got the same result.
The categories of the store do not load, the CSS is missing, it only displays the links.

Does anyone know if this module can solve the problem - https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=22017

Thanks.

Comment: That's strange, I have category/sub-category/sub-category/product working just fine. What does the error in the console say?

Comment: @LiviuVasile I have updated my answer to reference this information. I would suggest removing your website URLs from these comments just for your own privacy

Comment: I succeeded with base href, now I have base href on all pages of the site.

But i still have problem with load css. When i access a link css directly in browser with ssl, in console i receive: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

All links in console are: xGET https://domain/Accesorii/catalog/view/theme/fastor/css/bootstrap.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found), ... all links are same

Comment: That's strange, when I test the url I see no value for the base href. Try this URL https://domain/Accesorii/Bratari and look at the `<head>` value